# removeObject removes random object instead of the specific one

Tags: java

I'm making this 2D shooter game in Java as a Learning project.
I currently have one enemy Class in the game as a start. If I have multiple of those enemies on the screen and one of them dies by my bullets, a random enemy will die out of those on the screen. I know that having the same enemy in several classes with a seperate Health is a solution, but a very bad one. There must be Another way of doing this?

Comment: The solution is to fix the bug in your program, but it will be hard for any of us to help based on what you've posted so far. Please try to improve this question. You could look at the [tour], the [help] and especially at the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no bug. It is me not knowing how to make it remove the specific enemy.

Comment: And that is the bug. Again I don't see how we can help based on what you've posted so far. I would imagine that Enemy has a health field, and when an individual Enemy object is hit, his health goes down, right? And how much it goes down will depend on how he was hit and with what. So why not have him die when his health is < 0, and when this happens have the Enemy object itself remove itself from the enemies list. But all the details of how this is implemented will depend on the details and structure of your code, something we know nothing about.

Comment: I have one enemy class, and it got 100 Health. Once my bullet hits it, his Health goes down by 20. After 5 hits a random enemy dies instead of the one I shot because all of the enemies share the same Health. So I either have to make many enemy classes doing the same thing with a seperate healthbar. Every enemy need a seperate healthbar.

Comment: `"...because all of the enemies share the same Health..."` -- This makes no logical sense, and looks like a bug. Why not have every enemy **object** have its own health field? And you shouldn't be posting important details about your question in comments. Instead this key information should go into your question as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34111666/edit), and then then notify us of changes in comments.

Comment: the best answer could be: 1 put your objects (ennemies) in an array 2 use a random function to select one 3 remove this ... can you code this, please ?

Comment: Hahaha I know it sounds stupid but when the enemies spawn they are basically the same enemy duplicated, which means the same Health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use static field in Enemy class instead of normal one, for example:

```
Enemy {
    static Health health;
    ... 
}
```

instead of

```
Enemy {
    Health health;
    ... 
}
```

Use non-static fields and in this case you can just have List < Enemy > enemies and get only one enemy object from it's, for example:

```
  enemies.get(3).setHealth(Health.Died) // died enemy with number 3
```

Comment: public static float BEHealth = 100; So this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's main problem in your code, replace to "public float BEHealth = 100;" and you can change health for every enemy separately.

Comment: Yeah it worked :) Thank you for helping me :D

Comment: If it's working fine, could you acept my answer that show this question is closed and not need new answer?

Comment: Yes of course but how do I do that? :D

Comment: Just tick this answer (tick at the left of answer before 0). More info this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: There we go. Thank you again :)

Comment: I cannot ask Another question for 90 minutes so maybe you can help me again? When I press SPACE a bullets spawns, but now at my player position, here is the bullet spawn code:
    // Player Shoot
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
     int x = 4;
     int y = 8;
     handler.addObject(new PlayerBullet(x, y, ID.PlayerBullet, handler));

Comment: I realize X and Y is in need of a change but don't know what to do.

Comment: You need use something like this: Player Shoot if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ int x = 4; int y = 8;
PlayerBullet bullet = new PlayerBullet(x, y, ID.PlayerBullet, handler)
handler.addObject(bullet); for(int i=0; i< len; i++) { bullet.setX(x + i); bullet.setY(y + i); sleep(100);} }